# Magento - Listing all Categories in footer

Tags: magento, categories, footer

I'd like to display all my available and active categories in my footer. Like here:
http://cl.ly/242T162h1l121D0f3Y30

I know how to display at least one:

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory()->getName();
```

Can you gibe me some tips? :)

Answer (score 4):

Add this in the `app/design/frontend/interface/theme/layout/catalog.xml` under the default tag:

```
<reference name="footer.menu">
    <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.footer" template="catalog/navigation/footer.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

And create a file `app/design/frontend/interface/theme/template/catalog/navigation/footer.phtml` with this content:

```
<div id="footer-navi">
    <ul class="clearfix">
        <?php echo $this->renderCategoriesMenuHtml() ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Afterwards, style the navigation with CSS :-)

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thank you, I'll check that out in the next hour and come back to you!

Comment: Nope, that doensn't work! .( Nothing happens! I'm jusing Magento 1.5

Comment: Sorry, Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation.html#drawItem is deprecated and I think Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation.html#renderCategoriesMenuHtml does exactly what we want... So could you please give the new version above a try and tell us the result in Magento 1.5?

Comment: Strange - in 1.4.1.1 it works perfectly... Could you copy paste the exact error in e.g. pastebin?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using your theme then open app/design/frontend/your_package/your_theme/template/page/html/footer.phtml and put this code

```
<ul class"footer">
<?php $helper = $this->helper('catalog/category') ?>
<?php foreach ($helper->getStoreCategories() as $_category): ?>
<li><a href="<?php echo
Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->setData($_category->getData())->getUrl(); ?>"
title="<?php echo $_category->getName() ?>"><?php echo $_category->getName() ?></a></li>
 <?php endforeach ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create local.xml in app/design/frontend/rwd/[your-theme]/layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Add this in the app/design/frontend/rwd/[your-theme]/layout/local.xml under the default tag:

```
<reference name="footer">
            <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.footer" template="catalog/navigation/footer.phtml" />
</reference>
```

And create a file app/design/frontend/rwd/theme/[your-theme]/catalog/navigation/footer.phtml with this content:

```
<div class="links footer-navi">
<div class="block-title"><strong><span>Our products</span></strong></div>
    <ul>
        <?php echo $this->renderCategoriesMenuHtml() ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```